# Use if statements with a number variable in JS

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I am working on a gallery.
So basically my idea works like this:
The value of my variable **picnumber** is 1.
If you click on the *next* button it will trigger my function **nextpicture**, and of course if you click on the *previous* button it will trigger my function **previouspicture**.

So what is the job of those functions?

- **nextpicture** = **picnumber** + 1
- **previouspicture** = **picnumber** + 1

Ok, so for example we have clicked on **nextpicture** once the value of **picnumber** should be *2* (if the value is *2* it should show *002.jpg*)

I want to achieve that it shows a different picture on whether the value of **picnumber** is 1 - 6

I tried to do this with if and else if statements, however it didn't work.

```
var picnumber = 1;
function nextpicture(picnumber){
picnumber = picnumber + 1
}
function previouspicture(picnumber){
picnumber = picnumber - 1
}
if (picnumber == 1){
document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/001.jpg";
document.getElementById('galleryprevious').style.display = 'none';
}
else if (picnumber == 2){
document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/002.jpg";
}
else if (picnumber == 3){
document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/003.jpg";
}
else if (picnumber == 4){
document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/004.jpg";
}
else if (picnumber == 5){
document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/005.jpg";
}
else if (picnumber == 6){
document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/006.jpg";
document.getElementById('gallerynext').style.display = 'none';
}
else {  
document.getElementById('gallery').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<img id="gallerypicture" src="" alt="Photo">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="previouspicture(picnumber);"><div id="galleryprevious"></div></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="nextpicture(picnumber);"><div id="gallerynext"></div></a>
```

As you can see in my first and in my last if statement, I'd like to hide the div to click *previous* or *next*, so the value of **picnumber** can't be lower than 1 or higher than 6 (since I only have 6 pictures in this gallery)

Comment: your if statements will not be re-executed when you change `picnumber` value. you have to wrap them in an other function and call it in `nextpicture ` and `previouspicture` after changing picnumber value. Also actually the global `picnumber` variable is not updated at all as you hide it with `picnumber` parameter  of prev/next function

Comment: Those if statments do not magically get rerun when the variable is updated. Put it in a function and call it after you update the number.

Comment: There is no reason for all the repeated code: `var i = 1; var num = ("00" + i).substr(-3); console.log(num);`

Answer (score 1):

You are only running the `if` statements that set the image source once. You would need to run them after each change to the `picnumber` variable.

You can put them in a function, so that you can run them from each function that changes the variable, and also run it to set the initial image:

```
var picnumber = 1;
setImage();

function nextpicture(){
  picnumber = picnumber + 1
  setImage();
}

function previouspicture(){
  picnumber = picnumber - 1
  setImage();
}

function setImage() {
  if (picnumber == 1){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/001.jpg";
    document.getElementById('galleryprevious').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (picnumber == 2){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/002.jpg";
  } else if (picnumber == 3){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/003.jpg";
  } else if (picnumber == 4){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/004.jpg";
  } else if (picnumber == 5){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/005.jpg";
  } else if (picnumber == 6){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/006.jpg";
    document.getElementById('gallerynext').style.display = 'none';
  } else {  
    document.getElementById('gallery').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="gallerypicture" src="" alt="Photo">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="previouspicture();"><div id="galleryprevious"></div></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="nextpicture();"><div id="gallerynext"></div></a>
```

Note: Don't send the `picnumber` as a parameter to the functions. The parameter will be a local variable inside the function, so you won't change the global variable.

Another note: You are hiding the `galleryprevious` and `gallerynext` elements at some points, but there is no code to show them again. I think that you would want to set them as hidden/shown each time. Gershom Maes has some code [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724984/69083) that could handle that issue.

---

You can simplify the code in the function like this (while also making the links reappear):

```
function setImage() {
  var id = picnumber.toString();
  while (id.length < 3) {
    id = '0' + id;
  }
  document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/" + id + ".jpg";

  var prev, next;
  if (picnumber == 1) {
    prev = 'none';
  } else {
    prev = 'block';
  }
  if (picnumber == 6) {
    next = 'none';
  } else {
    next = 'block';
  }
  document.getElementById('galleryprevious').style.display = prev;
  document.getElementById('gallerynext').style.display = next;
}
```

Comment: Why not pad `picnumber` and get rid of all but one of the if statements?

Comment: @Archer: That's a good idea, but I wanted to keep it closer to the original code.

Comment: @Archer I deleted mine because Guffa updated the code of his post

Comment: this answer is incomplete, but I've just realized that mine is too! we've both solved half the problem - I think if chanceless draws from both our answers they can solve the problem

Comment: @Hacketo and I responded to your comment after he'd changed it.  I think we agree with each other.  Let's just delete all the things :p

Comment: Well a new bug is going to be the button does not show up.

Comment: @GershomMaes: Yes, I was thinking about that issue too. I don't think that's the main issue, so I added a note about it.

Comment: @epascarello Indeed, but I solved the problem and replied to Gershom Maes answer.

Comment: @GershomMaes Yep, it's interesting how you guys focused on two different mistakes of mine.

Comment: @Archer I appreciate it how Guffa wanted to keep closer to my code and now I use it. However I'd still be interested how your way would work.

Comment: @chanceless: I added a suggestion above for how you can create the image name by padding the picture number.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand this code at all. My skills in JS aren't that advanced yet.

Comment: @chanceless: I made the code a bit clearer, and refrained from using the conditional operator, have a look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
var picnumber = 1;
function nextpicture(picnumberLocal){
    picnumber = picnumberLocal+ 1;
    setImage();
}
function previouspicture(picnumberLocal){
    picnumber = picnumberLocal- 1;
    setImage();
}

function setImage(){
    if (picnumber == 1){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/001.jpg";
    document.getElementById('galleryprevious').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (picnumber == 2){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/002.jpg";
    }
    else if (picnumber == 3){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/003.jpg";
    }
    else if (picnumber == 4){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/004.jpg";
    }
    else if (picnumber == 5){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/005.jpg";
    }
    else if (picnumber == 6){
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/006.jpg";
    document.getElementById('gallerynext').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {  
        document.getElementById('gallery').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
setImage();
```

Comment: `nextpicture` and `previouspicture` update a local variable `picnumber` so I guess it can't work

Comment: the element will always have `display=none`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

JS:

```
var picnumber = 1;
function nextpicture()
{
   picnumber++; // increment the picture number

   // if the picnumber is bigger than 6 then we do nothing
   if (picnumber > 6) {
       return;
   }

   setImage();

   // if picnumber is 6 then we don't show the gallerynext button anymore
   if (picnumber == 6) {
       document.getElementById('gallerynext').style.display = 'none';
   }
   // if picnumber is 2 then we must to show again the previous button
   else if(picnumber == 2) {
       document.getElementById('galleryprevious').style.display = 'block';
   }
}

function previouspicture()
{
   picnumber--;

   if (picnumber < 1) {
       return;
   }

   setImage();

   if (picnumber == 1) {
       document.getElementById('galleryprevious').style.display = 'none';
   } else if(picnumber == 5) {
       document.getElementById('gallerynext').style.display = 'block';
   }
}

function setImage() {
    var imgNum = picnumber.toString();
    while (imgNum.length < 3) imgNum = '0'.concat(imgNum);
    // set the picture source depending on the picnumber value
    document.getElementById('gallerypicture').src = "img/gallery/" + imgNum + ".jpg";
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="gallerypicture" src="img/gallery/001.jpg" alt="Photo">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="previouspicture();"><div id="galleryprevious"></div></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="nextpicture();"><div id="gallerynext"></div></a>
```

Please note that if you hide the next/previous buttons you also must to show them again

Comment: Why @epascarello? it is a string concatenated with a number.. it will result in another string..

Comment: Which is the reason for downvoting? where are the argues?

Comment: If the OP has 10 images it would be 010.jpg most likely and not 0010.jpg (and I did not downvote and people do not have to explain their votes) I know your answer works with what OP has, not future proofing it.

Comment: man.. it has 6 pictures.. the example I wrote is for 6 images.. I didn't took in consideration that situation.. I thought he is smart enough to modify the script in order to be able to use more than 9 pictures.. this is not a reason for downvoting.. If he has 100 pictures then he will write 100 if statements?

Comment: I bet someone down voted your code because you copied the logic twice instead of doing it all in one method. Hence why I did not give you an up or down vote. Answer is not wrong, just not the best way of handling it.